# ios - Core Bluetooth: How to read data after response?

Tags: ios

I'm working on a project where I communicat over BLE. I can successfully send Data and receive data package from - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error

But I cannot receive a command that arrives after a few seconds. Anyone know how to set up a function which is called when I can read data after response?

Comment: If the peripheral is updating a characteristic value independent of a read request you need to enable notifications on the characteristic and then you will get a call to `didUpdateValue` when the peripheral changes the value

Comment: the point is that it is already enabled via the setNotifyValue. i receive the ak and should receive the package after 20 seconds but instead i receive nothing

Comment: After you enable notifications, do you get a call to [`didUpdateNotificationStateFor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518768-peripheral) with no error?  If so then it is up to the peripheral to issue notify/indicate on the characteristic when it has new data. There is nothing more you need to do on the central side.

Comment: no from there unfortunately I no longer receive anything